# Create EXC_BAD_ACCESS on purpose

Tags: objective-c, debugging, exception, crash, exc-bad-access

I would like to play around with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` to learn to debug it, and found that it is rather difficult to create such a situation.

I would like to see the use of "Enabeling Zombie Objects" in Scheme

Where is it when you need it?

Not even this work - setting build setting to not using ARC:

```
myobj *m = [[myobj alloc] init];
[m release];
[m dealloc];

 m = nil;
[m hello];
```

Some of the very good suggestions like:

```
int * array = (void *)0xDEADBEEF;
    array[2] = 10;
```

It only make Xcode stop saying bad access at the line, I need worse :-)

I have seen situations where it ends up in main.m where it is the hardest to debug. Can you create one?

Comment: Closely related: [Why is EXC_BAD_ACCESS so unhelpful?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2060435)

Comment: I would like to see the use of "Enabeling Zombie Objects" - thanks to asking.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
- (void) badAccess
{
    void (*nullFunction)() = NULL;
    nullFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means you're trying to access memory that you're not allowed to. That being the case, almost any setting of a pointer to an arbitrary address will raise this exception double-quick:

```
NSString * s = (__bridge id)(void *)0x8BADF00D;
[s uppercaseString];
```

Or

```
int * array = (void *)0xDEADBEEF;
array[2] = 10;
```

I'm not sure how helpful this will be for practicing; I think it'll be way too obvious what's going on, but that's how you do it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `strcmp(0, "");`